# Is it possible to add new control to Prism application without recompilation?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have just one module in `Prism` application. Let this module have name `ModuleA` and application name is `"CoolAppl"`. This application is cool and it works really okay in production. Once some guy would like to add new button, for example `"Delete Person"`, to this application `"CoolAppl"`.

**My question is can I or another guy from another city add new button `"Delete Person"` to `ModuleA` of application `"CoolAppl"` without recompilation any module just by adding dll with necessary button `Delete Person`?**

If it is possible, please, provide me direction where I should dig/search:).

I am using a such **mechanism of navigation**:

```
 Uri wholeView = new Uri("ModuleA", UriKind.Relative);                                
 regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheBottomRegion, wholeView);
 var currentView = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Views.ElementAt(0);
 regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Remove(currentView);
```

And  class to identificate modules looks like that:

```
public class ModuleAModule : ModuleBase, IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public ModuleAModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base(container, regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override void InitializeModule()
    {            
        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.TheWholeRegion, typeof(LoginControl));
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IViewModel, MyViewModel>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MySuperControl>();            
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no general answer to your question. We don't even know how do you implement navigation, view discovery, and so on. Be more specific, describe your app, provide relevant code.

Comment: @dymanoid I've added new code. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no recompilation means "not recompile everything", then you can just recompile ModuleA. If it means "recompile nothing at all", you're out of luck.
If the new button doesn't need to be in ModuleA, you can create a new ModuleB without either recompiling CoolAppl or ModuleA (but you need to compile ModuleB).

You might have put a plugin-system in place, though, that loads the buttons from plugins, then you can add another plugin for the new button.

Comment: Should I recompile my `CoolAppl` to have ONE `unityContainer` among `bootstrapper`, `ModuleA` and `newly added Control` from another guy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The unity container is created by the bootstrapper and the same for all modules. Depending on your module catalog, you have to either recompile the app, edit a configuration file or just put the new module in the right place (i.e. folder).

Comment: if I put new control(`ModuleByBill`) in right place, then it is possible to communicate between existed `ModuleA` in `CoolAppl` and newly added `ModuleByBill` without recompliling `ModuleA` and `Bootstrapper`?

Comment: Sure, that's the way EventAggregator works - you define events (i.e. classes) in a shared assembly, and some method in some module can publish the event and another one in another one can subscribe to it. Those modules need not know anything of each other. If you need new events, of course, you need to update the shared assembly or add a new one. Then, if you want an existing module to subscribe or publish the new events, you have to change its code and recompile. But as long as you're fine with the existing events, no existing modules need to bee changed.

Comment: Wow! Could you give some link where I can see example! I would like to implement it! Is it possible to "paste" new control from ModuleByBill into ModuleA without recompiling ModuleA and bootstrapper?

Comment: If ModuleA hosts a region that ModuleByBill registers a view for, sure, this will work. As for an example, I'll edit one in my answer above, but probably not this evening...